# Swift: Rounded Buttons

Tags: swift, rounded-corners

I am following the following tutorial on how to round the sides of buttons:

https://blog.supereasyapps.com/how-to-create-round-buttons-using-ibdesignable-on-ios-11/

I have created a new Swift code file as it has suggested and entered the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RoundButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        sharedInit()
    }

    func sharedInit() {
        refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius)
    }

    func refreshCorners(value: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = value
    }

    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15 {
        didSet {
            refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius)
        }
    }

}
```

I cannot see find the Corner Radius option in the "Identity Inspector" as shown in the animation on the website to create rounder buttons. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? Greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out adding the cornerRadius var:

```
@IBDesignable class RoundButton: UIButton {

  @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15 { didSet { refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius) } }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }

   .
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help @AppleCiderGuy, I finally got it working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `cornerRadius` to the following, to include `@IBInspectable`:

```
@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15 {
    didSet {
        refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius)
        layer.masksToBounds = true     // Could include this
    }
}
```

`@IBInspectable` allows you to access the property within storyboards, the interface builder.

You could also include `layer.masksToBounds = true`, so the corners are sure to get rounded even if `masksToBounds` in the storyboard is unchecked. However, you cannot apply both rounded corners and a shadow at the same time, but there are many workarounds available.

Answer (score 0):

It is my universal extension for `UIView`. You can move it to only for `UIButton`. Thus you can use 2 methods from interface to make rounded corners.

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var roundRadius : CGFloat {
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self.roundRadius
        }
    }

    /// automatically set cornerRadius as half of height
    @IBInspectable var isRounded : Bool {
        set {
            let radius = newValue ? self.frame.height/2 : 0
            self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        }
        get {
            return self.isRounded
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Agisight, thanks for replying! The only issue i have with your method is that you can only see the changes in the simulator, I want to see the physical changes before using the simulator (while still in the editor), can you help me with that?

Comment: there is no way to see in Storyboard editor. But in runtime for both simulator and real device you will see rounded views as you specified parameters